# Replacing all Commas of multiple CSV sheets before copying into an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, csv, replace

I have written VBA code that can copy the necessary information of multiple sheets into one Excel sheet.

One column contains numbers that have decimals (0,24 for example) which get separated when put into an Excel sheet.

How can I exchange all commas for dots so the columns stay as a whole?

After that I will reformat it by hand which isn't an issue with the amount of data I need to process.

```vb
Sub Mehrere_Dateien_auswaehlen()

Dim arrDateien As Variant
Dim wbQuelle As Workbook
Dim LetzteZeile As Long
Dim cntDatei As Long
Dim rngQuelle As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

arrDateien = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Exel-Dateien (*.cs*),*.cs*", MultiSelect:=True)

If IsArray(arrDateien) Then

    For cntDatei = 1 To UBound(arrDateien)

        LetzteZeile = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Set wbQuelle = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=arrDateien(cntDatei))
        Set rngQuelle = wbQuelle.Worksheets(1).Range("B2").CurrentRegion

        Intersect(rngQuelle, rngQuelle.Offset(1, 0)).Copy

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & LetzteZeile + 1).PasteSpecial

        wbQuelle.Close Savechanges:=False

    Next cntDatei
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

MsgBox "Erfolgreich zusammengeführt"

MyVar = Empty

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because the last used **Text-to-columns** (*or Default*) settings are set to **split-on-comma**. If you run a delimited Text-to-columns on a single **non-empty** cell, with no options selected (either manually, or via a script) you effectively clear out that setting and it won't split your values.

Assuming you'll want to do this with a script: the following lines, that you'll need to run before pasting anywhere - will 'clear out' the setting:

```
With Range("A1")
    .TextToColumns Destination:=.Offset(0, 0), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End With
```

Note - this uses `A1` but doesn't actually alter it at all. As long as it's a non-empty cell on the active sheet it will work.

Comment: Wow this made things way better! But it sadly still isn't there yet... Sadly the digits after the comma are still separated. I will try to attach a picture somewhere for you.

Comment: I attached the picture below the code that I am running.